# Creating and rotating ellipses in python, whilst checking for collisions

Tags: python, packing, collision

I've managed to create a bit of code that creates various discs and checks for collisions, but how would I go about doing it for ellipses instead?

```
height = 100
width= 100
circles = 15
radius = 4
xL = []
yL = []
count = 0
print("Placing ", circles, "circles on a" , width,\
      "x", height, "grid...")
for j in range(circles):
    x = randint(0,width-1)
    y = randint(0,height-1)
    if len(xList)>0:
        for i in range(len(xL)):
            distance = sqrt((xL[i] - x)**2 + (yL[i] - y)**2)
            if (distance < radius*2):
              print("Circle ", j, "collides with circle ", i)
              count += 1                  
    xL.append(x)
    yL.append(y)
print("Complete.", count, "collisions.")
```

Would I need to go about re-writing the code completely?
Also as a follow up I've been able to implement an algorithm that moves the discs ever so slightly and then accept or reject the move if they've come closer together. With ellipses its a bit different, as I'm going to need to rotate them. How would I do that?

Comment: With ellipses it's a lot different, the math is much more involved, so plan on a rewrite. The first thing you need to determine is a way to detect intersections (if that's what you mean by "collisions") between two arbitrarily sized and rotated ellipses. This will be tricky because ellipses can intersect one another in multiple time and in multiple ways.

Comment: Detecting is the only problem I'm going to have problems with I think. I think I can create ellipses by having 5 lists, one for its x co-ordinate, y co-ordinate, small radius, big radius and the angle. I want to be able work out the intersection/collisions without using something like pygame, pymunk

Comment: In theory you should be able to determine the intersection of two arbitrary ellipses analytically given the equation of each obtained from the information about each one you're keeping. However be aware the answer can be 0-4, or an ∞ number of points (the latter case occurring when they're exactly the same ellipse). In your sample code all the circles are the same radius, will that be true of the radii and angles of your ellipses?

Comment: Yeah all the ellipses have the same major and minor axis, all that is different is the angle they're rotated on

Comment: Although it doesn't deal with rotated ellipses, the article [Find the Points of Intersection of Two Ellipses](http://www.analyzemath.com/EllipseProblems/ellipse_intersection.html) looks like a good place to start.

Comment: You may be able to simplify the problem by transforming the two ellipses so that one of them is centered at the origin with it's axes parallel lined up with the x & y Cartesian coordinate system -- that will allow it's equation to be expressed in canonical form: `x**2/a**2 + y**2/b**2 = 1`.

Comment: Say I have the 2 equations for the elipses, in the link you posted, he does simulaneous equations to find out they intersect, as silly as it sounds what would happen if he tried to work it out and they didnt intersect?

Comment: I think when they don't intersect, you'll get complex rather than real roots when you solve the [quadratic formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Quadratic_formula). This happens when the [discriminant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation#Discriminant) of the quadratic equation is less than zero (i.e. you need to the square root of a negative number).